# How to parse timezone with date

Tags: linux, bash, date, parsing, timezone

How do we get the date utility to parse the timezone strings?

```
$>date -d "2018-02-21T02:22:33.221" "+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3N %Z"
2018-02-20T14:22:33.221 EST
```

But

```
$>date -d "2018-02-21T02:22:33.221 EST" "+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3N %Z"
date: invalid date `2018-02-21T02:22:33.221 EST'
```

This the local info:

```
$>uname -r
2.6.32-696.13.2.el6.x86_64

$>date
Tue Jan 16 09:58:52 EST 2018

$>date --version
date (GNU coreutils) 8.4
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by David MacKenzie.
```

Comment: What is your system's time zone?

Comment: Your Q needs to specify that you are using RHL. Good luck.

Comment: Works for me on Ubuntu 16.04, with "T" or space as separator. `date --version` is `date (GNU coreutils) 8.25`; what's yours?

Comment: BTW, this is not a programming question and should better be asked over at https://unix.stackexchange.com; that's where the real experts on this subject are. And don't cross-post, migrate the question.

Comment: @Murphy when you program on bash it is a programming question :) but unix.stackexchange.com perhaps is a good idea .... but how do you migrate questions?

Comment: Tell a moderator (answer is dated, but AFAIK still valid): https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266749/migration-of-code-questions-from-stack-overflow-to-code-review

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) allows you to replace `T` with space. Just do it, and your command will work fine:

```
# date -d "2018-02-21T02:22:33.221 EST" "+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3N %Z"
date: invalid date `2018-02-21T02:22:33.221 EST'
```

but:

```
# date -d "2018-02-21 02:22:33.221 EST" "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%3N %Z"
2018-02-21 10:22:33.221 MSK
```

Answer (score 1):

`date -d` is not the reverse of `date +format`, it can only accept some string from `man date`

> ```
>   -d, --date=STRING
>           display time described by STRING, not `now'
> DATE STRING
>    The  --date=STRING  is  a  mostly  free  format  human  readable  date string such as "Sun, 29 Feb 2004 16:21:42 -0800" or
>    "2004-02-29 16:21:42" or even "next Thursday".  A date string may contain items indicating calendar  date,  time  of  day,
>    time  zone,  day  of week, relative time, relative date, and numbers.  An empty string indicates the beginning of the day.
>    The date string format is more complex than is easily documented here but is fully described in the info documentation.
> ```